# About the $\sigma_{xy}$ in the integer quantum Hall effect (or quantum anomalous Hall effect)

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

We know that $\sigma_{xy}$ in the integer quantum Hall effect (or quantum anomalous Hall effect) can be calculated by the Berry curvature, but we also know that $\sigma_{xy}$ is calculated by the properties of the body!

Why it can be explained as edge state to some extent? I know edge-boundary correspondence, but what is the physics in it? I hope that is a elegant explanation about that.

Comment: Have you looked at the Landauer-Büttiker formalism?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I know that. But I don not think it's a explanation that I hope.

Comment: I suggest you to clarify which kind of explanation your hoping for, because as is your question looks a bit unclear.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano why body conductivity correspond to a edge conductivity?

Comment: An edge state is not associated to an edge conductivity.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano oh? Why? Can you explain more strictly?Thank you!